# How to get color cycle list working for \draw in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the MWE with a line specified by angles and a circle specified by \draw. I am able to get the colors cycled for the other lines plotted with \addplot. However, it does not work for \draw. How to get color cycles working for lines plotted with \draw?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.9,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal,
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        cycle list name=exotic,
        ]
        \addplot+[solid,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,10) (1,1)};
        \addplot+[dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,1) (1,10)};
        \addplot+[loosely dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(1,1) (1,10)};
        \draw (1,1) -- ++(45:2cm) -- ++(90:3cm);
        \draw[solid,line width=1.0pt] (axis cs:5.5,5.5) circle [radius=1];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw` is a `tikz/pgf` command and not a `pgfplots` command. I think that that could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if/how you can access the current state of the `cycle list` and apply that in a `\draw`, but you could alternatively do all the parts you show with `\addplot`.

I show two methods for the line with relative coordinates. One (see the fourth `\addplot` below) is really only practical if you  have few points. The other one is more flexible. You just specify the relative coordinates in a table, and the cumulative sum (i.e. the absolute coordinate) is calculated by `pgfplotstable`.

The circle is a simple parametric plot.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.9,
    }

% read in numbers
\pgfplotstableread{
x y
1 1
2*cos(45) 2*cos(45)
0 3
}\data

% create new columns with cumulative sum
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma+\thisrow{x}}]{cumx}{\data}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma+\thisrow{y}}]{cumy}{\data}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal,
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        cycle list name=exotic,
        ]
        \addplot+[solid,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,10) (1,1)};
        \addplot+[dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,1) (1,10)};
        \addplot+[loosely dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(1,1) (1,10)};
        \addplot +[mark size=5pt,ultra thick] coordinates {(1,1)({1+2*cos(45)},{1+2*sin(45)})({1+2*cos(45)},{4+2*sin(45)})};
        \addplot table[x=cumx,y=cumy] {\data};
        \addplot +[solid,line width=1.0pt,domain=0:360,samples=50,mark repeat=10] ({5.5+cos(x)},{5.5+sin(x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Exotic really is exotic :)

Answer (score 5):

You can access the styles via labelling the plots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal,
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        cycle list name=exotic,
        ]
        \addplot+[solid,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,10) (1,1)};\label{plot:1}
        \addplot+[dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,1) (1,10)};\label{plot:2}
        \addplot+[loosely dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(1,1) (1,10)};
        \draw[/pgfplots/refstyle={plot:1}] (1,1) -- ++(45:2cm) -- ++(90:3cm);
        \draw[/pgfplots/refstyle={plot:2}] (axis cs:5.5,5.5) circle [radius=1];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]